# How to pause the service while getting a incoming call and resume the service after call has ended?

Tags: android, android-service, phone-state-listener

My app is has a simple service, i need to pause that service when user makes or receive a call and service has to resume after call has ended.

Here is my **Main Activity** looks like:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    startService(intent);


    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}


class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_IDLE",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_RINGING",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}}
```

Here is my **Service class** file:-

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

private boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");

    isRunning = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (isRunning) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                }
            }

            stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    isRunning = false;

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
}}
```

From the **TeleListener class** in **MainActivity** i'm able to fetch the phone state. My problem is when the TelephonyManager is equal to **CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK** i need to pause the **MyService** and when the TelephonyManager is equal to **CALL_STATE_IDLE** i need to resume the **MyService**

Answer (score 0):

you need to use onCallStateChanged method.

put this lines in your onCreate() method,it will initialize object of TelephonyManager and will setup listener for you.

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
ListenToPhoneState listener = new ListenToPhoneState()
tManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

class definition of innerclass ListenToPhoneState will be looking like this,

```
private class ListenToPhoneState extends PhoneStateListener {

    boolean callEnded=false;
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            UTILS.Log_e("State changed: " , state+"Idle");


            if(callEnded)
            {
                //you will be here at **STEP 4**
                //you should stop service again over here
            }
              else
              {
                //you will be here at **STEP 1**
             //stop your service over here,
                //i.e. stopService (new Intent(`your_context`,`CallService.class`));
                //NOTE: `your_context` with appropriate context and `CallService.class` with appropriate class name of your service which you want to stop.

              }


            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            UTILS.Log_e("State changed: " , state+"Offhook");
                //you will be here at **STEP 3**
             // you will be here when you cut call
            callEnded=true;
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            UTILS.Log_e("State changed: " , state+"Ringing");
                //you will be here at **STEP 2**

            break;


        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Explaination: While the call,your listener will go through following states,

Step 1: `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`

initially your call state will be idle that is why the variable callEnded will have the value false.

Step 2: `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING`

now you are waiting for the receiver person to receive your call

Step 3: `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`

you cut the call

Step 4: `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`

idle again

NOTE: If you don't want to know when the call ends and what should be done after ending the call then just remove callEnded variable and stop the service whenever you enter in the block of `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: I have already declared all those. I need to pause and resume the service on CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK and CALL_STATE_IDLE

Comment: Its working fine, but it is working only when app is open, but i need to work all the time like a service.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pause or resume a service, you can start your service again when call ends. Inside `PhoneStateListener`'s `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` constant, start your service again! Using different states of `PhoneStateListener` as mentioned by @Tijo, you can decide when to start or stop your service.